get_cell_atlas_coords returns (-1, -1) based on direction
I'm trying to make conveyors return tile data based on what is colliding with raycasts. I have it pretty much working, but with one issue. If the tile is colliding from the left or top raycast, it cannot find the tile and returns (-1, -1) here is what my code looks like:
if $Raycasts/Left.is_colliding():
            raycast_on_wall = true
            var tile_map: TileMap = $Raycasts/Left.get_collider(0)
            var hit_pos = $Raycasts/Left.get_collision_point(0)
            var tile_pos = tile_map.get_cell_atlas_coords(0, tile_map.local_to_map(hit_pos))
            tile_map.set_cell(0, hit_pos, 0, tile_pos)
            var data = tile_map.get_cell_tile_data(0, hit_pos)
            conveyor_detect = data.get_custom_data("Direction")

(For the raycasts I'm using shapecast2ds for a wider detection range, which is why get_collider and get_collision_point includes an index. I still faced the issue when I used normal raycasts)
This is what is returned for each variable
I checked everywhere online for discussions and checked the docs several times, but nothing is talking about why it would be unable to find the tile based on the direction. I checked if it was a tile thing, but it's not. The code functions fine on the bottom and right raycasts, on every tile. The code in the script and editor is identical. (Yes, the instances where I specify the colliding raycast is different for the seperate types.

Since it's the top row and left column, I'm inclined to guess it's some rounding error or, depending on how you place the tiles, it's grabbing a negative value when you're expecting a zero.

@FrasherGray Thank you for the reply! Although it didn't end up being the issue, I appreciate your response

For any future devs, I found a solution. Not sure what the problem was, but a workaround is to find the coordinates of the collider rid, which finds the tile position relative to the tilemap; thus, not returning an invalid tile.
var hit_pos = tile_map.get_coords_for_body_rid($Raycasts/Left.get_collider_rid(0))
This also eliminates the need for setting the cell and makes the code look much cleaner; so it's a better method in many ways.
Note: I am using shapecasts for my collision detection. If you use normal raycasts, you do not need the index for the rid.
